# Padding a codepoint's binary representation with 0's

Tags: python

I am writing a function in python with signature

```
def function(codepoint):
```

Lets say the codepoint is 180, which binary representation is 10110100. Let's say I want to pad the codepoint with 2 0's so that is turns into 0010110100. What is the best way to do this in python? I am not allowed to convert it to a string using bin() and when I tried doing formatting my binary representation grew in length by a lot so I know I am not padding correctly. Any solutions to my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Does padding with zeros on the right change the value?

Comment: Can you write what you've tried so far?

Comment: What type is it if it isn't a string? If you just need to hit a certain width, you can use the string method `zfill()`

Comment: Why are you not allowed to convert it to a string using `bin()`? Is this a homework exercise?

Comment: Yes its a programming assignment for school and while I used bin() originally I had to backtrack since that approach is not allowed @Elmex80s

my instructor said its any type that points to code: ex: it can be hexadecimal like 0x83, it can be ord(some_value), it can be binary 0b1010100, etc. 


I have used zfill when working with strings when I converted the value. Backtracking I tried to use int(format(codepoint, '11b')) or something of that sort but that did not work